# When is the following inequality true? $ \int_0^1 \lvert f-g\rvert \leqslant \max_{x\in[0,1]}\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

> Let $ f,g \in \mathcal{C}([0,1])$. Then we have
>   $$ \int_0^1 \lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert dx \leqslant (1-0)\max_{x\in[0,1]}\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert $$

Now, is it only true for continuous functions in $[0,1]$?

Comment: You can of course simplify your statement of the Question since $1-0 = 1$, but perhaps you have in mind to hint at a more general result.

Comment: Are you asking for conditions under which equality holds?  Or are you asking for extra (or relaxed) conditions that make the inequality true?

Comment: Yes, conditions and if it can be generalized to any real interval [a,b]

Answer (score 3):

With max replaced by sup, it's true whenever $|f(x) - g(x)|$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[0,1]$.

For any interval $[a,b]$ with $a \le b$, you have
$$ \int_a^b |f(x) - g(x)| \; dx \le (b-a) \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x) - g(x)|$$